# angular not getting exception message from .net core

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, error-handling

So I would like to get in console an json array with message, what would be equal with "Your direct manager have no account for your area."

But all I am getting is "Http failure response for https://localhost:44385/api/Option/Post: 500 Internal Server Error"

Note: When looking at dev tools -> network -> post -> response, then it shows html and css with right error message included, but no idea how to get it out from there.

Controller

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public void Post(Option option)
{
    throw new NoBudgetAccountException();
}
```

Exception

```
[Serializable]
public class NoBudgetAccountException : Exception
{
    public NoBudgetAccountException() : base("Your direct manager have no account for your area.")
    {
    }
}
```

Angular apiService

```
addOrUpdateOption(option: ITrainingOption): Observable<Response> {
    return this.post<Response>("api/Option/Post", option);
  }
```

Angular component

```
submitOption(option: ITrainingOption) {
        this.apiService.addOrUpdateOption(option).subscribe(() => {
            this.isAddOptionShown = false;
            this.getHeadlines(this.selectedYear);
          },
          err => { console.log(err); });
      }
```

Comment: Are you using `Http` or `HttpClient`?

Comment: I am using HttpClient

Comment: Does your `console.log` get printed? You should be able to use `console.log(err.error)` to get the body

Comment: Yes, it prints the whole body, but I would like to get only this "Your direct manager have no account for your area." so I can put it in error field and show it to user.

Comment: Okay, can you please edit your question to show what the full response looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

usually with .net stuff when you do something like

```
throw new Exception("This is a custom exception");
```

It doesn't actually give you this message, instead it throws you an error html page
[image]

If you want to return a message and parse it in angular use an IActionResult instead and return BadRequest("message")

```
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public IActionResult test(Option option)
    {
        return BadRequest("This is an error message");
    }
```

After doing this your error message should show in err.error

[image]

Comment: Will accept this, but used StatusCode() instead of BadRequest() and will use it in try and catch to get message from exception.

Comment: Yup, you can send anything really. You can even extend these.
Ok(), BadRequest(), StatusCode()

etc..